# VB.NET BigInteger Literal

Tags: .net, vb.net, biginteger, literals

How can I represent very long BigInteger Literals in VB.NET, especially Hexvalues? Is there an appropriate suffix like in other languages signaling that the Literal should be treated as a BigInteger?

Edit: I was a bit unsettled because such a suffix exists in some .NET languages like F# but I couldn't figure out somehow if that is the case for VB.NET or even C#, and if there is no - why?

Comment: [msdn and google are your friends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is not a built in type like int32.  You have to create them.

Comment: PLease clarify "very long BigInteger "

Comment: @Trevor a 128-256 Byte hexadecimal value

Comment: @no_mindset Read the documentation. It has examples.

Comment: @no_mindset..ahh...right... Having Long and Integer in the same sentence confused me... Been doing this way too "Long" LOL